# Why don't we have a distinctive symbol for 10?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems, decimal-expansion

For example: Why don't our digits go: $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a$ instead of using only nine symbols and $0$: $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$.

Comment: Then it could go to 11 too!

Comment: How do you represent 0 in this system?

Comment: Well, you have to stop sometime or you'll run out of symbols!

Comment: In a given base $b$, which can be any positive integer greater than or equal to $2$, your symbols are $0,1,2,\dots,b-1$, and you represent numbers larger than $b-1$ by using multiple digits. Most of humanity now uses $b=10$; why this choice was made is a question for a social scientist of some sort, not a mathematician. In computing you find people using $b=16$, taking the letters $A,B,C,D,E,F$ to represent $10,11,12,13,14,15$ respectively.

Comment: Each digit would represent 10 numbers instead the only time you can write 0 is when it's alone, it seems more logical this way

Comment: the question is not why we use base 10, it's why we don't have symbols for every value in base 10

Comment: So you're suggesting that our symbols be $1,2,\dots,9,a$ where $a$ encodes $10$, instead of $0,1,\dots,9$? Then as Mnemonic said, how do you encode $0$? Similarly, how would you encode 11? According to the usual rules of number bases, $a1$ would encode $101$, not $11$.

Comment: One of the nice features of having 0 is that the last digit is always consistent.  In your system, $a - a = 0$, but $1a - a = a$.

Comment: Why not go directly from a to 11 and so on, that way every digit can hold all values in base 10

Comment: OK, so 11 works the same. Now how do you write 20? Is it the same? You also still have not said how you write $0$.

Comment: 20 would be written as 1a therefore terminating the need for 0, but having last digit consistency is a good point i suppose using 0 is only for making numbers more readable ?

Comment: How would you write eleven, then ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I asked that already, it is the same, you fill the 10s place with a $1$. The interesting thing is when you start filling another place with a $a$, for example this system writes $100$ as $a0$.

Comment: @ian: with the $1\to a$ numeration, there is no $0$.

Comment: Yes, that point has also been made already...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number $N$ can be represented in our standard base 10 number system as follows

$$
N = \sum_{i=0}^{m} d_i10^i
$$
with
$$
0 \leq d_i \leq 9.
$$

To represent $N$ in zero-less base 10, we have the same sum, but with
$$
d_i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a= 10\}
$$

Some examples of numbers written in zero-less base 10

$N = 100 = 9a$

$N = 1000 = 99a$

$N = 1025 = a25$

Note that both number systems have ten symbols available to represent a number. The zero-less representation is simply 'shifted forward' by one number. Both number systems are equivalent in expressive power except that the zero-less system **cannot represent zero naturally**. One could write $1-1$ to mean zero, but that is the tradeoff for not having to use two symbols to represent ten.

Comment: Isn't being able to represent numbers with fewer digits also another advantage?

Comment: @i-o You save a digit on 10,100,1000,etc., nowhere else. Also, by that logic we should use some huge base like 60 or something.

Comment: The optimal base is $3$, assuming that the "cost" of a representation equals the number of digits to be written times the number of distinct digits.   For a number $n$, this is $b \log_bn$, which is the smallest when $b=e$. But for many other reasons, base $2$ is by far the best.

Comment: @i-o Yes it is! There are advantages and disadvantages to every number system. The ancient Babylonians used base 60. Although I don't believe anyone knows for sure why they used base 60, it is perhaps because 60 has so many factors, making calculations such as multiplication much easier.

Comment: @Samasambo: base $60$ numeration is an absolute nightmare. You have to use single-digit addition and multiplication tables of $3600$ entries. This made computation only accessible to professionals.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree base 60 is a nightmare. The babylonians utilized what are known as reciprocal tables to help carry these out. Here's a link so some info on that, http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma105/reciprocals3600.html

Comment: @Samasambo: interestingly, theyused only two digits: the one and the ten, combined in an heterogeneous numeration system. The tables of reciprocals are only for divisions.

Answer (score 0):

Because $0$ is absolutely necessary (arguably, it's the most important number), and adding another digit would make it **base 11**.

Base $11$, unlike base $12$, which is an awesome, makes for a terrible numeral system because $11$ is a prime number. Number table for base 11:

$$
\begin{array}[pos]{r}
 0 &  1 &  2 &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6 &  7 &  8 &  9 &  a \\
10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 1a \\
20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 2a \\
30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 3a \\
40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 4a \\
50 & 51 & 52 & 53 & 54 & 55 & 56 & 57 & 58 & 59 & 5a \\
60 & 61 & 62 & 63 & 64 & 65 & 66 & 67 & 68 & 69 & 6a \\
70 & 71 & 72 & 73 & 74 & 75 & 76 & 77 & 78 & 79 & 7a \\
80 & 81 & 82 & 83 & 84 & 85 & 86 & 87 & 88 & 89 & 8a \\
90 & 91 & 92 & 93 & 94 & 95 & 96 & 97 & 98 & 99 & 9a \\
a0 & a1 & a2 & a3 & a4 & a5 & a6 & a7 & a8 & a9 & aa \\
\end{array}
$$

11 is a prime number, so all fractions not of the form $x/a^y$ will recur, making arithmetic difficult:

$$
\frac{1}{2} = .\overline{5}, \ \ \ 
\frac{1}{4} = .\overline{28}, \ \ \
\frac{1}{5} = .\overline{2}, \ \ \
\frac{1}{a} = .\overline{1}
$$

Comment: I did not suggest base 11 as i've stated above, by using a distinct symbol for 10 there would be no use for 0